# Local node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a NodeJS application scaffolded as such:

```
- server/app.js (runs the main app)
- package.json (for the main app)
- haraka/package.json (generated by Haraka SMTP server)
- haraka/plugins/some.plugin.js
```

The main app is run directly using `node app.js` while Haraka is run using Haraka's command installed globally (`haraka -c haraka`) and plugins which are written in JavaScript will then run.

How can I get the plugin files in Haraka to use the `node_modules` in the parent app?

Comment: The necessary modules for haraka is in its `package.json`. Why do you want to not to use that?

Comment: @thefourtheye Let's say I want to have Haraka require a file in server/api/some.api.js. This file is shared between the main app and Haraka, and both uses it to communicate with the database. What would be the best way around it?

Comment: But that file is not in `node_modules` directory, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye No, the file required by some of Haraka's plugins then require some node modules in the parent app.

Comment: Then why do you have a separate `package.json` in haraka?

Comment: @thefourtheye Haraka generates the haraka folder when you run `haraka -i haraka`. Would removing the package.json make it resolve node modules from the parent directory?